# JavaFX positioning of a button

Tags: java, javafx-8

How do I set the position of a Button in JavaFX? My Code:

```
bZero = new Button();
bZero.setPrefSize(45, 20);
mainPane.getChildren().add(bZero);
```

Comment: Use whatever [`layout pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG) suits your needs.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific positioning? What type of layout is `mainPane` and where do you want to position your button?

Comment: I want to place it at a specific position and its a Pane

Comment: With specific position do you mean the X/Y co-ordinates?

Comment: when its possible yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a container that does not manage layout, such as a plain `Pane`, then you can use

```
bZero.setLayoutX(...);
bZero.setLayoutY(...);
```

or, equivalently,

```
bZero.relocate(...);
```

However, as suggested in the comments, it is far preferable to use a [pane that manages the layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG) for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setX and setY properties of the button to position it in a Pane

```
bZero = new Button();
bZero.setPrefSize(45, 20);
mainPane.getChildren().add(bZero);
bZero.setLayoutX(100); // Sets the X co-ordinate
bZero.setLayoutY(200); // Sets the Y co-ordinate
```